# Highcharts - Legend item padding

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

There seem to be a problem with the padding of text for label items in Highcharts. I get very different results in Firefox compared to Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/moppa/cMXyG/18/

[image: Example of difference]

If I inspect the elements in the browser the **tspan** tag has a height of 16px in Chrome, but 20px. In FF it looks like some pixels has been added as padding, since the text does not fill up the whole tag. I have experimented with line height and font-size settings of the `legend.itemStyle`, but no luck.

Does anyone have any ideas? Firefox 25.0.1 and Chrome 31.0.1650.57m

Attaching code to be compliant with the JSFiddle restriction:

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container'
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        itemMarginTop: 0,
        itemMarginBottom: 0,
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'middle',
        padding:0
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]},
    {
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]},
    {
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]},
    {
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]},
    {
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]},
    {
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]}]

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with the **itemMarginBottom** properties like this:

```
legend: {
    layout: 'vertical',
    itemMarginBottom:7,
    align: 'right',
    verticalAlign: 'top',
    itemStyle: {
        font: '9pt Raleway,Helvetica,sans-serif',
        color: '#A0A0A0'
    },
    itemHoverStyle: {
        color: '#FFF'
    },
    itemHiddenStyle: {
        color: '#444'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you check with master version? This one example: http://jsfiddle.net/cMXyG/19/ `.`

For me it looks fine, see:

- FF:

[image: Firefox]

- Chrome:

[image: Chrome]

There is small difference (~1px) probably caused by different calculations for lineWidth.

Comment: Hi. No change in my browsers. This image is taken from your fiddle. http://imgur.com/OJYZJTp

Edited my post with browser version numbers.

Comment: I tested in FF 25 (Windows 7 version, MacOSX version) and in all cases iti si displayed as Pawel mentioned. Could you point me which system do you use?